# $\sum_{n=0}^m \binom{m}{n}\Gamma\Big(n-\frac{1}{2}\Big)\Gamma\Big(m-n-\frac{1}{2}\Big)=0$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

How to prove that for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $m\geq2$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^m \binom{m}{n}\Gamma\Big(n-\frac{1}{2}\Big)\Gamma\Big(m-n-\frac{1}{2}\Big)=0$$

Any hint?

Comment: Are you sure that's true? Try $m=1$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following identity is pretty simple to prove (for instance, through Euler's Beta function):

$$ \sum_{h\geq 0}\frac{\Gamma\left(h-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(h+1)} z^h =-2\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{1-z}$$
and for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ your (convolution) sum is just $m!$ times the coefficient of $z^m$ in the Taylor series at the origin of $\left(-2\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{1-z}\right)^2$. If $m\geq 2$, that is zero.

Comment: Why the (convolution) sum is just $m!$ times the coefficient of $z^m$ in the Taylor series at the origin of $\left(-2\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{1-z}\right)^2$?

Comment: @bojica: By Cauchy product, $$ \sum_{n=0}^{M}a_n b_{M-n} = [z^M]\left[\left(\sum_{h\geq 0}a_h z^h \right)\cdot \left(\sum_{h\geq 0}b_h z^h \right)\right].$$

Comment: Here $a_n = b_n = \frac{\Gamma(n-1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)}$, hence your sum is computing a Taylor coefficient in a square (times $m!$).